# Declaration of a javascript function twice

Tags: javascript, function

I need to declare a function 2 times with a different treatements 
let me explain more the overwritting :

```
function test(var){

    //treatments
}

function test(var){

   alert("something" +var);

}
```

and here is the HTML code :

```
<select name="choices" onchange="test(this)">

    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>

</select>
```

how can I make them working both without making everything in one function  ?

Comment: You can't have two functions with the same name. What makes you think you need to have the function named the same thing? What differentiates when you need to call which one?

Comment: I am using a volusion website and I don't have access to modify a function , and I need to open a modal dialog in the execution , I can't modify even the html code , I have one place to put a javascript code in the head of page ,  does it make sence ?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as method/function overriding in javascript. Whichever function is defined last takes precedence. You could split the logic into different functions but you would need some sort of main function that decides which one to use.

Javascript does have `switch` statements though, so that might be a good fit for your problem. It would be a little neater than a large if/else block. Something like the following might work.

```
function test(el){
  switch(el.value){
  case 1:
    alert('option 1 selected');
    break;
  case 2:
    alert('Option 2 selected');
    break;
  default:
    alert('Another option was selected');
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using a volusion website and I don't have access to modify the function , and I need to open a modal dialog in the execution of that function , I can't modify even the html code , I have one place to add a javascript code in the head of page , does it make sence ?

Comment: In that case I would bind a function to the click event of that element and put whatever logic you want in there. If jquery was present you could easily do: $('select[name="choices"]').bind('click', ...

Comment: can you clarify more please , I need to bind and unbind right ?

Comment: You would only need to unbind if you didn't want your function to be called anymore when the select is clicked. Also depending on how the page is constructed you might need to use something like the jquery 'on' function. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Just imagine you are java script runtime... How will you detect such ambiguity? Answer is no. You can't define functions with same signature in the same scope.

But my advice is to use some kind of "namespaces":

```
var yourNamespace1 = {

    test: function(var) {
        //treatments
    }
};

var yourNamespace2 = {

    test: function(var) {
        alert("something" +var);
    }
};
```

It is simple JS objects with defined functions for key "test"

And access the functions by `yourNamespace1.test(...)` and `yourNamespace2.test(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to have different behavior based on the choice in the dropdown. Here's one way to do that:

```
<select name="choices" onchange="test(this)">

    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>

</select>
```

```
function test(el)
{
   var num = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
   if (num == 1)
   {
       // case 1
   }
   else if (num == 2)
   {
       // case 2
   }
}
```